# How can include space and german characters in laravel request rules?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

Currently I am working on laravel 5.5 project. I need to validate a field. That field must be required, alpha numeric and space would be accept. I have added rules like  `'street'  => 'required|alpha_num|max:255'`. But space not accept and german language not accepting eg:`Betrag für diese`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What about adding a custom validation rule? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel uses this pattern that already supports German characters:

```
/^[\pL\pM\pN]+$/u
```

You can add whitespace characters with `\s`:

```
'street' => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\pM\pN\s]+$/u|max:255'
```